# PostgreSQL query with UNIQUE values returned based on condition

Tags: postgresql

Its an example of a table from PostgreSQL.
I learning the SQL query and cant find anything to help me pass this.

What I`m working to achieve is:

Return UNIQ(DISTINCT) values of WNR WHEN tdate >='2020-01-13 00:00:01.757000'

```
WNR     tdate                       T1  T2  T3
2   '2020-01-06 00:05:23.229000'    8   18  15
2   '2020-01-06 00:05:23.725000'    11  4   7
2   '2020-01-06 00:05:31.578000'    19  12  6
3   '2020-01-13 00:00:01.655000'    9   9   3
3   '2020-01-13 00:00:01.757000'    5   11  16
3   '2020-01-13 00:00:05.778000'    16  17  16
4   '2020-01-20 00:00:11.925000'    18  13  4
4   '2020-01-20 00:00:12.177000'    18  3   15
4   '2020-01-20 00:00:12.694000'    7   12  7
5   '2020-01-27 00:00:04.860000'    19  3   14
5   '2020-01-27 00:00:05.056000'    14  18  8
5   '2020-01-27 00:00:05.107000'    18  7   14
```

Result expected should be 3,4,5

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select distinct values in Postgresql you can use DISTINCT clause.

From [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html): SELECT DISTINCT eliminates duplicate rows from the result. SELECT DISTINCT ON eliminates rows that match on all the specified expressions. SELECT ALL (the default) will return all candidate rows, including duplicates. (See DISTINCT Clause below.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT WNR
FROM table_name
WHERE tdate >='2020-01-13 00:00:01.757000';
```

Comment: I really dont know what I was doing and didn't work ... strange, I have used the same DISTINCT ...  thank you, its return what I need, so thank you for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome @Num3illia! Remember to select the answer that best answers your question, so that the question is marked as answered.